# How to extract a table without totally scraping it from a url but by clicking on the "export" button using python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I wanted to **scrape** a table from a website putting the required date range and other conditional parts into it. But the problem is the table that is generating after putting the required detail doesn't contain a few columns which are required for my reporting purpose.

But when I'm exporting the table in a CSV format by clicking on the "export" button manually, it contains all the desired columns in it.

So, now I want to know how can I get this CSV formated file automatically using python as it will help me, later on, to produce the required dataframe through reading it from the downloaded path.

Here's my code :

```
import datetime
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

......

with Session() as s:

Today = pd.datetime.now().date()
Yesterday = Today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

Search_Data = {"dp_type": "all","from_date[date]": Yesterday,"from_date[time]": "00:00","to_date[date]":Today,"to_date[time]":'00:00',"salesorder_schedule": 'singledelivery',
                   "op": 'List Export', 'selectall_oid': '1','overview_delivery_cost': '0',
                    'form_token':Form_token, "form_id": 'clc_saleorder_report_form'}
    s.post(url, Search_Data)
```

Here **op** is the defined option that I want to do with this **URL** and I choose to export.

The code has run with zero (0) error but the problem is I don't see any file has downloaded anywhere after the successful execution of this code.

Can anyone help what is the missing tricks here?

Comment: What's the website url?

Comment: It's an official url and prior to log into it you will be required to provide credential.That part is successfully done. I'm not rightfully okay with sharing the url with you @trenton..sorry for that

Comment: Ok.  You could also try `df = pd.read_html('web site url')` which reads tables with table tags [pandas.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html). If there are multiple tables, then `df` will be a list of dataframes so use something like `df[0]` to access the actual dataframe.